# is there an easy way to re-route ALL requests to a specific page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

we have a relatively complex (10 controllers, about 25 views) contest website. Contest will be over soon and we are required to put a "contest is closed" page to be displayed instead of all other pages. But with few exceptions - for example, Contest/Rules should still display the rules.

To rephrase it - how can I make sure that no action will be called from any of the controller except the ones I somehow specify? Basically I need something like this in my routing table:

```
if (requestedAction is Contest/Rules)
   allow;
else
   redirect to Contest/Closed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more controller and bind it with desired view, specify this controller in routes.
You are looking for too much easy way.
[Wanted to add as comment, but can not because stupid reputation policy]